# Convert Speech Start and End Time into Time Series

Tags: r, dataframe, dcast

I am looking to convert the following R data frame into one that is indexed by seconds and have no idea how to do it. Maybe dcast but then in confused on how to expand out the word that's being spoken.

```
startTime endTime           word
1     1.900s  2.300s         hey
2     2.300s  2.800s         I'm
3     2.800s      3s        John
4         3s  3.400s       right
5     3.400s  3.500s         now
6     3.500s  3.800s           I
7     3.800s  4.300s        help

Time           word
1.900s         hey
2.000s         hey
2.100s         hey
2.200s         hey
2.300s         I'm
2.400s         I'm
2.500s         I'm
2.600s         I'm
2.700s         I'm
2.800s         John
2.900s         John
3.000s         right
3.100s         right
3.200s         right
3.300s         right
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution can be achieved using `tidyr::expand`.

**EDITED:** Based on feedback from OP, as his data got duplicate `startTime`

```
library(tidyverse)
step = 0.1
df %>% group_by(rnum = row_number()) %>%
  expand(Time = seq(startTime, max(startTime, (endTime-step)), by=step), word = word) %>%
  arrange(Time) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-rnum)

# # A tibble: 24 x 2
# # Groups: word [7]
#    Time word 
#   <dbl> <chr>
# 1  1.90 hey  
# 2  2.00 hey  
# 3  2.10 hey  
# 4  2.20 hey  
# 5  2.30 I'm  
# 6  2.40 I'm  
# 7  2.50 I'm  
# 8  2.60 I'm  
# 9  2.70 I'm  
# 10  2.80 John
# ... with 14 more rows
```

**Data**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"startTime endTime           word
     1.900  2.300         hey
     2.300  2.800         I'm
     2.800      3        John
     3      3.400       right
     3.400  3.500         now
     3.500  3.800           I
     3.800  4.300        help",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: i removed the s in my original text and I am getting an error with this, any suggestions?                                                            Error in seq.default(startTime, (endTime - step), by = step) : 
  'from' must be of length 1

Comment: group_by(word) is in there

Comment: Are you using exactly same data the one I have mentioned in my question or changed? If you are using changed one then i need info that. May be you can use `dput` on that data.frame and share as part of question

Comment: Another possibility is that your data.frame got duplicate `word`. Like `right` was spoken twice.You need to change the `group_by` part as `group_by(startTime)` in that case.

Comment: Your data works so it must be something on my end. Thanks again for the help

Comment: Just look at my previous comment. If there are duplicate words then you can replace `group_by` part as `group_by(startTime)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168472/discussion-between-andrew-olson-and-mkr).

Comment: I have modified my solution. It should work on your data.frame.

Answer (score 0):

`dcast()` is used for reshaping data from long to wide format (thereby aggregating) while the OP wants to reshape from wide to long format thereby filling the missing timestamps.

There is an alternative approach which uses a *non-equi join*.

#### Prepare data

However, `startTime` and `endTime` need to be turned into numeric variables after removing the trailing `"s"` before we can proceed.

```
library(data.table)
cols <- stringr::str_subset(names(DF), "Time$")
setDT(DF)[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) as.numeric(stringr::str_replace(x, "s", ""))), 
          .SDcols = cols]
```

#### Non-equi join

A sequence of timestamps covering the whole period is created and right joined to the dataset but only those timestamps are retained which fall within the given intervall. From the accepted answer, it seems that `endTime` must not be included in the result. So, the join condition has to be adjusted accordingly.

```
DF[DF[, CJ(time = seq(min(startTime), max(endTime), 0.1))], 
   on = .(startTime <= time, endTime > time), nomatch = 0L][
     , endTime := NULL][]   # a bit of clean-up
```

> ```
>     startTime  word
>  1:       1.9   hey
>  2:       2.0   hey
>  3:       2.1   hey
>  4:       2.2   hey
>  5:       2.3   I'm
>  6:       2.4   I'm
>  7:       2.5   I'm
>  8:       2.6   I'm
>  9:       2.7   I'm
> 10:       2.8  John
> 11:       2.9  John
> 12:       3.0 right
> 13:       3.1 right
> 14:       3.2 right
> 15:       3.3 right
> 16:       3.4   now
> 17:       3.5     I
> 18:       3.6     I
> 19:       3.7     I
> 20:       3.8  help
> 21:       3.9  help
> 22:       4.0  help
> 23:       4.1  help
> 24:       4.2  help
>     startTime  word
> ```

Note that this approach does not require to introduce row numbers.

`nomatch = 0L` avoids NA rows in case of gaps in the dialogue.

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
DF <- fread("
rn startTime endTime           word
1     1.900s  2.300s         hey
2     2.300s  2.800s         I'm
3     2.800s      3s        John
4         3s  3.400s       right
5     3.400s  3.500s         now
6     3.500s  3.800s           I
7     3.800s  4.300s        help
", drop = 1L)
```